# define jpa entity classes outside of persistence.xml

Tags: java, orm, jpa

Is there a way to define jpa entity classes outside of persistence.xml (i.e. in a separate file)?

Being able to not have persistence.xml as an external file would also suffice.

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Edit:
Sorry I was not clear. This is in a Java SE environment.
Also, I would like to not have a listing of some.class.AClass in my persistence.xml file.
This is because I would like to create this list of classes dynamically and reference a file containing this list.

Edit2:
Managed to solve this by writing a persistence.xml file at build time before it is packaged. If anyone is interested, I used scannotations to discover all the classes annotated with @Entity and wrote them to the persistence.xml file in target/classes/META-INF (using maven).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to stop including the <class> elements in your persistence.xml?

Comment: yes. and sorry, i forgot to mention this is in a Java SE environment.

Comment: If you don't mind not being portable, some providers do support discovery in a Java SE environment. So please clarify if portability is a concern (and what JPA provider you're using).

Comment: I am using the standard Sun EJB JPA with Hibernate 3.5. Also, portability is a concern because I am using maven to test against a changing external jar containing my entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Java SE environment, portable applications **must** list classes explicitly in the `persistence.xml`. From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 6.2.1.6 mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes
>
> The following classes must be
>   implicitly or explicitly denoted as
>   managed persistence classes to be
>   included within a persistence unit:
>   entity classes; embeddable classes;
>   mapped superclasses.
>
> The set of managed persistence classes
>   that are managed by a persistence unit
>   is defined by using one or more of the
>   following:
>
> - One or more object/relational mapping XML files
> - One or more jar files that will be searched for classes
> - An explicit list of the classes
> - The annotated managed persistence classes contained in the root of the
>     persistence unit (unless the
>     `exclude-unlisted-classes` element is
>     specified)
>
> (...)
>
> A list of named managed persistence
>   classes may also be specified instead
>   of, or in addition to, the JAR files
>   and mapping files. Any mapping
>   metadata annotations found on these
>   classes will be processed, or they
>   will be mapped using the mapping
>   annotation defaults. The class element
>   is used to list a managed persistence
>   class. **A list of all named managed
>   persistence classes must be specified
>   in Java SE environments to insure
>   portability. Portable Java SE
>   applications should not rely on the
>   other mechanisms described here to
>   specify the managed persistence
>   classes of a persistence unit.
>   Persistence providers may also require
>   that the set of entity classes and
>   classes that are to be managed must be
>   fully enumerated in each of the
>   `persistence.xml` files in Java SE
>   environments.**
>
> All classes contained in the root of
>   the persistence unit are also searched
>   for annotated managed persistence
>   classes and any mapping metadata
>   annotations found on them will be
>   processed, or they will be mapped
>   using the mapping annotation defaults.
>   If it is not intended that the
>   annotated persistence classes
>   contained in the root of the
>   persistence unit be included in the
>   persistence unit, the
>   `exclude-unlisted-classes` element
>   should be used. **The
>   `exclude-unlisted-classes` element is
>   not intended for use in Java SE
>   environments.**
>
> The resulting set of entities managed
>   by the persistence unit is the union
>   of these sources, with the mapping
>   metadata annotations (or annotation
>   defaults) for any given class being
>   overridden by the XML mapping
>   information file if there are both
>   annotations as well as XML mappings
>   for that class. The minimum portable
>   level of overriding is at the level of
>   the persistent field or property.

If portability is not a concern, some provider do support entity discovery in a Java SE environment (for example, EclipseLink, [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging)).

If portability is a concern, using a third party container like Spring would help.

Comment: Hi, I have a maven app and the .jar name and path changes during time. Can I somehow scan all classes with Hibernate 3.6?

Comment: Also, in Hibernate Chapter 2, there's `Ejb3Configuration`. Can I somehow add a `persistence.xml` to it? Basically, I want to have "core" module with PU, and add entities in plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing and able to package your entity classes in a JAR file along with the persistence.xml file, then you don't need to list each entity in a `<class>` element. When a JAR is deployed with a persistence.xml file in the META-INF directory the JAR will be searched at runtime for any classes that have the `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: Only in a Java EE environment. But the question is really not clear.