# hibernate separate jar lib

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate application. All entity classes plugged in in a separate jar file. The config is the following:

```
<bean id="myEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="packagesToScan"  value="mypackage" />
</bean>
```

And persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0" >
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="mypackage.domain.MyInformixDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I run my application,I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

When I tried to debug, I found a section:

```
file: package org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter

if ( results.length == 0 ) {
    LOG.noPersistentClassesFound( query );
}
```

Line 130, hibernate version is 4.3.8.Final

So, my entities seems has not been loaded. Why? Why can't it scan them from a jar file? I checked package names, persistence.xml is in META-INF folder, etc. What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

The stacktrace is below:

```
     javax.faces.FacesException: #{InsertServices.onSelectSubscriber}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at mypackage.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.findList(BaseDaoImpl.java:64)
    at mypackage.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.findNonRawList(BaseDaoImpl.java:73)
    at mypackage.dao.subscriber.impl.OrganizationDaoImpl.findByAccount(OrganizationDaoImpl.java:27)
    at mypackage.dao.subscriber.impl.OrganizationDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$441cab30.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at mypackage.dao.subscriber.impl.OrganizationDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79142731.findByAccount(<generated>)
    at mypackage.impl.SubscriberServiceImpl.findByAccount(SubscriberServiceImpl.java:83)
    at mypackage.impl.SubscriberServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$317992ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at mypackage.impl.SubscriberServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee0052f.findByAccount(<generated>)
    at mypackage.web.faces.beans.services.InsertServices.onSelectSubscriber(InsertServices.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

This is what I get with xml config

Comment: The persistence.xml it's in the application, not in the jar right?

Comment: Yes, the persistence.xml is in the application, I don't think it's a good idea to keep it in blabla.jar library. It should take all data from the application.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean 'search in jar file'. If you mean physically search it, I did, it's there. If you mean that I should load them dynamically somehow, I don't know why should I do that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the JPA that your entity are in external jars.

Reference: [JPA 2.0: Adding entity classes to PersistenceUnit *from different jar* automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380728/jpa-2-0-adding-entity-classes-to-persistenceunit-from-different-jar-automatic)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" ... >
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mysource</jta-data-source>

        <jar-file>lib/${common.jar}</jar-file>
        <jar-file>lib/${foo.jar}</jar-file>

        ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life! Also, as for me, I shouldn't specify the absolute path to a jar file, I used lib/myjar.jar and it found it in WEB-INF/lib/myjar.jar. Thank you