# Hibernate - mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm developing an application in Java with Hibernate.
I'm having trouble with relationships.

**Class Nucleo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nucleo")
public class Nucleo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "nuc_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "nuc_nome")
    private String nome;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "nuc_data_criacao")
    private Calendar dataCriacao;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nuc_id")
    private List<Telefone> telefone;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Pessoa.class, mappedBy="nucleo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Pessoa> funcionarios;
```

**Class Pessoa**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pes_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "pes_nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "pes_observacao")
    private String observacao;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "trabalha",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pes_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nuc_id")
    )
    private Nucleo nucleo;
```

It happens the following problem:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: br.edu.esaoabsp.sistemas.model.Pessoa.nucleo in br.edu.esaoabsp.sistemas.model.Nucleo.funcionarios
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
```

The nucleo attribute exists in the class Pessoa.
Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Please use English.

Comment: Possible to just try to try a simplest example and make it works (bi-dir relationship using a join table)? I don't see the need of using `targetEntity` there.  Can try to remove it and have a try agian?

Comment: check if `Nucleo` is defined in the `persistence.xml`

Comment: @AdrianShum I removed the `targetEntity` and I get the same error.

Comment: @KenChan I'm using @Entity. Is it necessary to define `Nucleo` in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: depend on your application environment . In Java SE environment , yes. In Java EE , it may not required.

Comment: @KenChan my app is JEE

Comment: @ThiagoGomes it is (kind of) required to be in persistence.xml no matter it is SE or EE. It is the way to tell JPA what are the entities.  However, depending on technologies you are using, there are other alternatives, which I have answered some similar question long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13756652/395202

Comment: @AdrianShum I did it and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Just wonder, assuming you do not have that bi-dir relationship (just to make thing simple), do both entities work (so you can read/update)?

Comment: @AdrianShum When I removed the relationship, the entities work fine.

Comment: just wonder... why you would have a JoinTable for One-to-Many relationship?  Shouldn't a One-To-Many relationship normally be modeled as FK at the "Many" side table?